# Asp.Net MVC4 Getting 500 internal server error after using custom session (Redis)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm using in-proc session state in my application & just change in-proc to custom.

After changing session state, some place I'm encounter with 500 internal error.

Here is my web.config entery

```
<add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="100.100.92.90" accessKey="" ssl="false" />
```

Can somebody can help me why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you share the exception that you are getting?

Comment: After changing here-there in web.config, here is the error , but suprisingly some links(urls) are working fine.     Server Error in '/' Application

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/undefined

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

Answer (score 0):

This is because Redis server is not reachable (Some Firewall issue)